# resourceID from image in assets subfolder only works for some files

Tags: android, drawable

I have an assets subfolder and images on it all png's some bigger, I'm writing a hybrid app from Angular so I pass via an interface the name of a file to pop it in an activity I pass only the name not the extession. It works for some files but not for others (a bigger one on my case) is there a reason for that???, I'm using this basic code below, the smaller file resID has a number for the bigger file it comes out as 0. The png with the problem does load on a basic page in angular, I want to pop a zoomer of that image. Probably I could place a copy in the Drawable res folder, but Angular needs it hanging from my assets.

```
image = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.cur_img);
    if( getIntent().hasExtra("imageResName") )  // set it to passed image
     { // a popup pass in the image
         String curResName =getIntent().getExtras().getString("imageResName");

         //  gte the di from a drawble ..it wprks 
         int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(curResName , "drawable", getPackageName());

          image.setImageResource(resID); 



     }
```

**UPDATE**: Yep that code will NOT work I could pull an SO answer where
 I probably misunderstood it ... this is the mod'ed code that will work

```
if( getIntent().hasExtra("imageResName") )  // set it to passed image
     { // a popup pass in the image


        String curResName =getIntent().getExtras().getString("imageResName");



         Bitmap bitmap=null;

         try
         {   // for image in: /assets/imagenes/xxx.png
             AssetManager assetManager = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
             InputStream istr = assetManager.open("imagenes/" + curResName + ".png" );
             bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
             istr.close();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             bitmap = null;  
         }
         finally
         {

           image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
         }
```

Comment: I've seen other replies where they claim the code above is supposed to work for files in the assets folder but I'm digging deeper and files in the assets folder are not supposed to get an ID, I have copies on the drawable that is why my code worked for some files. Are those replies wrong???

Comment: "the code above is supposed to work for files in the assets folder" -- nothing in that code will work with `assets/`. `getIdentifier()` only works on resources, and `getIdentifier()` for `"drawable"` only works for drawable resources.